# Is Drupal 8 and Symfony totally different or can use both?

Tags: symfony, drupal, drupal-8

I'm quite new to Drupal 8 and Symfony and I've been reading/looking at some YouTube tutorials on the Symfony. We are going to use Drupal 8 for our site. Does this mean we can't use Symfony? Is it one or the other? My understanding at this point is that we will do a majority of our site through theming and modules. Does this mean I don't know need to create a full Symfony site right out of the gate? Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: As the official site says "Symfony is a set of reusable PHP components ... and a PHP framework for web projects". Drupal is a CMS. Drupal uses Symfony (components). So if you're using Drupal, you are using (some) Symfony by default

Comment: Drupal 8 apps and pure Symfony 2 apps can coexist on the same server just fine.  But if you are mainly supporting Drupal 8 apps then there is really no need to dive into Symfony apps unless you just want to learn.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. And yes, at this point we're mainly going to use Drupal 8 to host many contents. Besides that, we're just going to use module and theming to pull data from our own server that provide API service.

Comment: What I got confused is that when I watched videos about Symfony, I don't see that it was used inside of Drupal 8. Symfony seemed to be on its own rather than hosted inside of Drupal 8. So, I want to make sure I understand Symfony enough make a sound decision. I've also seen another video that shows Symfony was being used to write modules for Drupal 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal 8 now uses symfony2 - if you are just beginning with Drupal, I wouldn't be concerned about symfony at all. Symfony is a collection of bundled php components - these libraries in turn drive some of the 'core' of D8.

For example, some of the Symfony2 components used in drupal : `HttpFoundation, HttpKernel, Routing, EventDispatcher, DependencyInjection, and ClassLoader`

You can see from the above, these are very low-level functionalities in the stack, likely things you will not mess with too much (at least at first), and rather just need to know how to access classes/methods (especially for things such as Routing and Dependency Injection)

Really I think it's a strategic move by Drupal to allow developers familiar with Symfony to acclimate much more quickly to the drupal environment. It's also keeping in mind that now if you write a really great php library, you can plug it into your drupal site, and then also contribute it back to the community so anyone using symfony could use it.

From what I can tell in your post, you really have no worries about the intermingling of the two - Drupal is much more of a traditional CMS, whereas Symfony is a collection of php components.

Some good articles about both of these: 
http://symfony.com/what-is-symfony
http://www.blinkreaction.com/blog/why-is-symfony-in-drupal-8-and-how-does-that-change-things

Good luck and happy coding